# How to check if the variation combination already exists in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Before registering Product Variations (myVariations), I need to check if variations already exist.

*One*:
I want to register variation 2 and 6. I need to look in the *allVariations* array for this variation that contains the same *product_detail_id*

*Two*:
2 and 6 would return true because both belong to the same product_detail_id (3)

2 and 4 would return false because:

2 belongs to product_detail_id 1

4 belongs to product_detail_id 2

If possible, I want it to return true or false

In the example below, I have 2 and 6 in the myVariations variable, but it could be more than two variations.

```
  console.log(allVariations)
  console.log(myVariations)

/* CONSOLE */
[ RowDataPacket { product_detail_id: 1, variation_id: 2 },
  RowDataPacket { product_detail_id: 1, variation_id: 5 },
  RowDataPacket { product_detail_id: 2, variation_id: 4 },
  RowDataPacket { product_detail_id: 2, variation_id: 6 },
  RowDataPacket { product_detail_id: 3, variation_id: 2 },
  RowDataPacket { product_detail_id: 3, variation_id: 6 } ] // allVariations

[ { variation_id: 2 }, { variation_id: 6 } ] // myVariations
```

Comment: Create an object whose keys are product_detail_id, and values are a `Set` of variation IDs. Then you can search the object to see if `Set([2, 6])` is a subset of one of the elements.

Comment: I'm going to research about Set. I'm a beginner. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use 2 `forEach` loops:

```js
var all = [{ product_detail_id: 1, variation_id: 2 },
  { product_detail_id: 1, variation_id: 5 },
  { product_detail_id: 2, variation_id: 4 },
  { product_detail_id: 2, variation_id: 6 },
  { product_detail_id: 3, variation_id: 2 },
  { product_detail_id: 3, variation_id: 6 }];
var myFalse = [{ variation_id: 2 }, { variation_id: 6 }, { variation_id: 7 }];
function hasAllVariations(allVariations, myVariations){
  var r = [], l = myVariations.length, a = [];
  myVariations.forEach(function(o){
    allVariations.forEach(function(q){
      if(o.variation_id === q.variation_id)r.push(q);
    });
  });
  if(r.length < l){
    return false;
  }
  r.forEach(function(o, k){
    r.forEach(function(q, i){
      if(k !== i && o.product_detail_id === q.product_detail_id && a.indexOf(k) === -1)a.push(k);
    });
  });
  return a.length >= l;
}
console.log(hasAllVariations(all, myFalse));
var myTrue = [{ variation_id: 2 }, { variation_id: 6 }];
console.log(hasAllVariations(all, myTrue));
console.log(hasAllVariations(all, [{ variation_id: 2 }, { variation_id: 4 }]));
```

Comment: Probably this makes much sense, mine is short but looks way too complicated by just using array function :/

Comment: If possible I would store `myVariations` Array, as just an Array of numbers. Then rewrite the code accordingly.

Comment: One moment, don't you check for produtc_detail_id ?

Comment: In tests 2 and 4 returns true =(

Comment: IT WORKED ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while, probably has a better way but this works as it supposed to:

Also works while for more than 2 elements

```js
const allVariations = [
  { product_detail_id: 1, variation_id: 2 },
  { product_detail_id: 1, variation_id: 5 },
  { product_detail_id: 2, variation_id: 4 },
  { product_detail_id: 2, variation_id: 6 },
  { product_detail_id: 3, variation_id: 2 },
  { product_detail_id: 3, variation_id: 6 },
  { product_detail_id: 4, variation_id: 1 },
  { product_detail_id: 4, variation_id: 2 },
  { product_detail_id: 4, variation_id: 3 },
];

const isContain = variation => !!variation.reduce((acc, my) => [...acc, allVariations.filter(all => my.variation_id === all.variation_id)], [])
  .reduce((acc, cur) => cur.find(e1 => acc && [acc].flat().some(e2 => e1.product_detail_id === e2.product_detail_id)));

console.log(isContain([{ variation_id: 2 }, { variation_id: 6 }]));  // true
console.log(isContain([{ variation_id: 2 }, { variation_id: 4 }]));  // false
console.log(isContain([{ variation_id: 1 }, { variation_id: 2 }, { variation_id: 3 }]));  // true
```

Comment: Does it work when the myVariations variable has more than 2 elements ?
From what I understand in your example, it's only for 2 elements

Comment: @John Just updated, now it works for more than 2 elements

Comment: IT WORKED
Thanks

Comment: Is the StackSlave example simpler ? I didn't understand your answer to his code

Comment: @John I started from using array functions at the beginning. But then I realized using loops is better for readability in this scenario. So I actually recommend StackSlave's answer, but if you don't care about how it's implemented, both ways are okay cuz they both work.